# Sql running multiple queries

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code to fetch 2nd highest salary in a company...

`select salary from org order by salary desc limit(1,1)`

above result will be one row ...with highest salary(100000) ,,,now i want to fetch all employes `emp_names` with the second highest salary.. how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add DISTINCT to your query (in case multiple people have the same highest salary), and join it like this:

```
select org.* from org
join (select distinct salary from org order by salary desc limit(1,1)) org_salary
  on org.salary = org_salary.salary
```

Working sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/838d8/15)

Comment: `LIMIT` is not supported inside an `IN ()` subquery. This will error.

Comment: That answer doesn't use an `IN()` subquery, it uses a joined subquery where `LIMIT` _does_ work.

Comment: just curious to know is there any other way..?

Comment: @user - sure, you could do it with two queries instead (one to get the salary, another to get all the employees with that salary) but not sure why you would want to.

Comment: k in case if i use two queries.. how to give `where` condition?

Comment: pass it as a parameter - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php